# what is the reason to skip softirqd wakeup in interrupt context

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to understand why `in_interrupt()` check in [raise_softirq_off](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/softirq.c#L665) removes the need to wake up  `softirq`. As I understand, `in_interrupt()` returns true if the code is being run in hard or softirq context. If it's the former, why isn't wakeup needed?

Comment: Scheduler always runs when interrupt returns to userspace.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84107/64699

Comment: The exit from hard IRQ will check for pending soft IRQs and wake up the soft IRQ daemon if necessary. See [`__irq_exit_rcu`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.4/source/kernel/softirq.c#L622).